# JSX Converter using React.createElement("h1", null) instead of React.DOM.h1(null)

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs

## JSX Transformer Causes Errors

When I convert my react files using the converter from **react-tools**

```
      $ jsx public/dev/jsx public/prod/js --no-cache-dir
```

Or when I convert with **grunt-react**

```
      $ grunt react
```

My production file breaks because the conversion uses `React.createElement` and the error says that this function is undefined.

```
      <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
```

converts to:

```
      React.createElement("div", null, 
      React.createElement("h1", null, this.state.title)
```

instead of:

```
      React.DOM.h1(null, this.state.title)
```

The live converter works fine because it uses `React.DOM.h1(null, this.state.title)`.  This line of code works well with react, but the `React.createElement()` function does not work and is not found.

How can I force my auto converter, either JSX or grunt, to convert to `React.DOM.h1(null)` instead of `React.createElement(h1, null)`. Why does the converter use this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error with the coffee-react-transform lib.  These libraries are getting updated for React 0.12. If you're still on React 0.11, you'll probably need to roll back grunt-react to a slightly older version, or bump up to React 0.12.

Comment: Thanks! If you use browserify, make sure to bump the version as well (0.17 worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I actually updated to React 0.12 and it started working...  Thanks.